# jquery .html() doesn't work in IE if an OBJECT tag is used

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
<div id="object-container">
    <object data="some-file.swf">
        <param name="src" value="some-file.swf" />
    </object>
</div>
```

I want to grab the contents of #object-container and inject them into a different place on the page.  The code I have to do this works fine in firefox, but in IE it's only getting the opening and closing object tags, not the param tags:

```
var code = $('#object-container').html();
$('#other-div').html(code);
```

Does anyone know how to reliably get the FULL HTML out of a div in IE?

EDIT: All other tags are working in IE

```
$('#other-div').html("Other HTML Code Displays Correctly <h1/>");
```

Thanks all

Comment: I tried this in IE 9 and all of the contents copied over just fine, http://jsfiddle.net/Xr5xS/, you'll need to inspect the results with the developer tools, but they're there.

Comment: @Cold Nope. [`<param>` is eaten](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d5VFr.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea why this happens on IE, you can try to use only javascript to do it:

```
var code = document.getElementById('object-container').innerHTML;
$('#other-div').html(code);
// or document.getElementById('other-div').innerHTML = code;
```

Hope this works

Comment: Nah, [`html()` calls `innerHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), so there's no difference.

Comment: Thanks All

It works nice with the JavaScript. 

    document.getElementById('other-div').innerHTML = code;

The issue is a JQuery bug as I think and explained in here [link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6444)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS code with `$('#object-container').clone().appendTo('#other-div');`